# Как найти минимальное значение не кратное 6 в массиве?

Tags: pascal

Минимальное значение я нашёл. Но как добавить условие, что минимальное значение не должно быть кратно 6?

```
var 
  a:array[1..20] of longint;
  i:longint;
  min: integer;

begin
randomize;
  for i:=1 to 20 do 
    a[i]:=random(2001)-1001;

  min:=a[1];
  for i:=1 to 10 do 
  if a[i] < min then
    begin
    a[i]:=min;
    end;

  for i:=1 to 20 do begin
    writeln('a[' ,i,'] = ', a[i]);
  end;
  writeln('min= ', min);

end.
```

Comment: А каковы признаки делимости на 6? Подумайте.

Answer (score 1):

```
if a[i] < min then
```

заменить на

```
if (a[i] mod 6 <> 0) and (a[i] < min) then
```

Ну и, само собой,

```
begin
    a[i]:=min;
end;
```

заменить на

```
begin
    min := a[i];
end;
```

И, конечно же, следует проверить при присвоении

```
min:=a[1];
```

не делится ли этот элемент на 6, и тогда выбрать другой...

Comment: Надо еще предусмотреть, что делать, если окажется, что все элементы массива делятся на 6.

Comment: @Yaant Это да? но этого в ТЗ вообще нет :) Пусть автор вопроса думает...